# iPad - Make a button more clickable in Safari?

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile-safari, ios5

Using an iPad, IOS5, is there anyway to make a button more clickable in the browser? I have a website using html 5 and I noticed that I sometimes have to click a button multiple times for the jquery to read the click event. Here is the html for a button I use:

```
<button class="button purple">SEARCH</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.button.purple').click(function() {

//Code goes here

});
```

Comment: I think that's a hardware issue. I've noticed that on multiple platforms. Is this happening *too* often? If it is only taking one or two clicks, it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple click events on that page, you might want to try `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('.button.purple').click(function(e) {

    //Code goes here

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is that the same as return false?

Comment: would using tap instead of click be a better option on a mobile device like an ipad?